# Reduce Size/ Polymorph into smaller creature wearing off in cramped space

Tags: pathfinder-1e

One of my players asked me what would happen if while under a polymorph spell reducing your size it ran out while you were in a space too small for your normal size.

For example you polymorph into a mouse and run down a pipe. You can't make it out and the spell runs out. Assuming this pipe cannot burst open what happens to the character?

I am looking for a RAW answer but if one is not available a generally accepted house rule is acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Shrink and Enlarge work in constrained environments?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16196/how-do-shrink-and-enlarge-work-in-constrained-environments)

Comment: @starwed Related yes but he quotes the enlarge spell description. This question is only about reduce size/polymorph running out.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but this reminds me of obe of the most dangerous building materials in the D&D system: Cows polymorphed into bricks.  If you accidentally clip the wall with *dispel magic*, the hallway is suddenly full of very large cows.

Comment: @Bobson I'd be hesitant to enter any structure built of [bone bricks the size of cows.](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/polymorphAnyObject.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Opinion**

In general you could assume that they are in a tight space (as per the [escape artist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/escape-artist) skill).

If the will not physically fit into the space they are currently in I would go down one of two routes:

**a)** Have them return to the closest size they can, but be completely unable to move.
The spell is jamming them against the available space. They will need to be rescued expand into any available space (making getting them out before they reach their normal size hard) Throw in some minor damage (to simulate being scraped along the surfaces as you expand) for good measure. Take care they do not use this to imprison enemies (or praise them if you think its clever). Otherwise...

**b)** I would treat it as if you had used [dimension door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) and appeared in an occupied space. Shunt them to a place you deem appropriate.

> **If you expand in a place that is too small for your original size you** take 1d6 points of damage and are shunted to a random open space on a suitable surface within 100 feet of the intended location.
>
> If there is no free space within 100 feet, **you** take an additional 2d6 points of damage and are shunted to a free space within 1,000 feet. If there is no free space within 1,000 feet **you die**

Bold is changed text.

Comment: I don't particularly like the dimension door solution, because there's no reason you'd suddenly start phasing through stone (or whatever) because you returned to full size.  I do like the first suggestion, though.

Comment: With regard to imprisoning enemies - giving them a chance to smash out of the enclosure would be reasonable, and that would essentially require the players to contain their enemies using materials that could have held that enemy anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Preliminary note: Neither [*polymorph*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph), nor the spells it references (like [Beast Shape II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape)), nor the [Transmutation (Polymorph)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) subschool has anything to say on this matter. The closest thing I could find was the wording of [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person):

> If insufficient room is available for the desired growth, the creature attains the maximum possible size and may make a Strength check (using its increased Strength) to burst any enclosures in the process. If it fails, it is constrained without harm by the materials enclosing it--the spell cannot be used to crush a creature by increasing its size.

However, applying this rule to the reversal of spells that make you smaller is not RAW. Though as far as houserules go it's sensible in that it uses existing rules and is constistent with them.

---

#### RAW approach

If *reduce person/monster* runs out, the creature's size will increase by only one category, which is usually a factor of 2 in all dimensions. This normally allows you to [sqeeze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Terrain-and-Obstacles):

> In some cases, you may have to squeeze into or through an area that isn't as wide as the space you take up. **You can squeeze through or into a space that is at least half as wide as your normal space.**

Of course, if you were already squeezing, the space you have might not be half as wide as your new size. Squeeze continues

> To squeeze through or into a space less than half your space's width, you must use the Escape Artist skill. [...]

which refers to [Escape Artist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/escape-artist). Squeezing through "a space where your head fits but your shoulders don’t" is a DC 30 Check that takes at least 1 minute.

Okay, so we have approximately two size categories down (Your head usually fits everywhere a small creature (like a kid) can squeeze through easily)

Now, let's assume you polymorphed an ogre (large) into a housecat (tiny), and that housecat proceeds to squeeze under a door, and Polymorph runs out. (Note: here's where RAW gets silly). You are no longer covered by the squeezing rules, and [thus you are](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Special-Movement-Rules)

> **Accidentally Ending Movement in an Illegal Space**
>
> Sometimes a character ends its movement while moving through a space where it's not allowed to stop. When that happens, put your miniature in the last legal position you occupied, or the closest legal position, if there's a legal position that's closer.

So by RAW, since you cannot be where you are, you get teleported all the way back to where there was a big enough space for you to be (likely squeezing). As I said: This is highly silly, and houserules are definitely called for.

Comment: I don't think, in that final sentence, *teleported* is the right word--more of a rapid expulsion from the current impossible space. Movement's taking place, although forced, so the creature's provoking attacks of opportunity, triggering traps, and other horrible things all along the route to the new space... probably screaming the whole time.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: That sounds like RAI.  RAW says "move your mini" which sounds like pseudo-magical teleportation.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: It says "put your miniature". There's no mention at all of movement taking place. There's no forced movement, teleportation, or any other movement-related thing. The game system is, essentially, rubber-banding you directly to a place where you can legally end your movement.

Comment: @MooingDuck Now I'm imagining a Monty Python-esque hand of God reaching down and bodily moving the character, the frustrated voice-over intoning, "What's *wrong* with you? Don't you understand square occupancy?" Seriously, this is interesting--essentially 2 votes for, for example, landing on someone after a fall causing teleportation or "rubber-banding" under *Pathfinder*'s RAW instead of movement. Why the resistance to movement and an insistence on an unfathomable, unnamed alternative?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: So, given your interpretation, what do the rules say about the character's movement triggering a sliding wall trap, thus trapping the character in an illegal space and making it impossible for said character to move to a legal space? The only way the illegal space rules make sense is if the game fixes the illegal state that it is in as expediently as possible.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Because I thought this was a RAW question, but looking again, it is not.  Any sane DM should just houserule whatever seems sane at the moment.

Comment: @Ellesedil The game freezes and we reboot? Really, though, the obscure *D&D 3.5* 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *small enough* [trans] (*Dragon* #308 21)--one of my personal favorite *D&D 3.5* spells--has rules for such an occasion. Absent official *Pathfinder* rules and other *D&D 3.X* rules, I'd use that spell's rules in my *Pathfinder* game.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: "The game freezes and we reboot?" Yes. If you want to treat it differently, house rule away. But by the letter of the text in the rules, you are to **put** your miniature in the closest legal space. Keep in mind that this rule is in the event of an accident. If a player does this on purpose, feel free to throw everything at them and let their environment crush their character as it enlarges.